# How to register a resource to a class loader in runtime?

Tags: java, classloader, embedded-resource, urlclassloader

I found similar questions on how to add a file or a class, but in this case
the resource to be registered is going to be constructed at runtime and kept in memory.

So to illustrate this, say I want to create configuration properties for some library I will be using.
Before I initialize this library, I would like to construct the properties resource and put it on the classpath so that the library can pick it up and use it.

But in this case, properties resource won't be on a filesystem. It should be in memory, and when the library tries to load it, it should be served directly
from memory.

I imagine I should define a custom `ClassLoader` and override the methods related to resource retrieval. Also, I should somehow convert my in-memory data to a `URL` form.
But I don't know how to convert something like this to `URL` (I am guessing it has to do something with `URLConnection`).

I am aware that the library probably won't be able to find this resource if this special class loader is not "visible" from this library. If it is not part of the class loader chain.